# How to identify which Page number was clicked in DataPager

Tags: asp.net

I have a listview and DataPager control. Now when I click a page number on the DataPager, the

> ListView1_PagePropertiesChanging(object
>   sender,
>   PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)

event is fired. Now, I would like to identify which page number of the DataPager was clicked. For example, if Page 3 was clicked, then I would like to get the value 3. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which language are you writing the code behind, C# or VB

Answer (score 1):

you can try a code like this.

```
  protected void ListView1_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        int pageindex = e.StartRowIndex / e.MaximumRows;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs` as [members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) that have some of the information you might need